# Запятая после "вообще"

Tags: вводные-слова

Можно ли "вообще" в этих случаях считать вводным словом?

И вообще начальнику нашего отдела надоели исполнительные устройства, он целиком погрузился в АСУ.

А вообще это были «руки» МИНХИММАШа — главным был плановый отдел, куда стекались планы и отчеты арматурных заводов...

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае "вообще",  скорее,  является членом предложения, что следует из семантики сообщения, а также структуры и интонации.

Сравнить: И вообще (говоря),  начальнику нашего отдела (уже) надоели исполнительные устройства, (поэтому) он целиком погрузился в АСУ. В том предложении "и вообще" можно считать вводным словом, его можно выделить паузой.

Comment: А мне кажется, что "вообще говоря" скорее можно подставить во втором случае: А вообще (говоря), это были руки МИНХИММАШа. Окончательно запуталась.

Comment: Окончательное решение делается по контексту, тут такое тонкое различие. Если можно подставить "вообще говоря", то это вводное слово. Можно еще для проверки подставить "а вообще же", тогда это обстоятельство.

Answer (score 2):

Вводное слово "вообще" -  то же что «вообще говоря». Наречие "вообще" -  то же, что «в целом, в общем, совсем».
В первом предложении больше вообще больше под вводное слово. Вряд ли можно сказать: ***и целом/в общем  начальнику нашего отдела надоели исполнительные устройства, он целиком погрузился в АСУ.***

Во втором предложении "вообще" сомнений не вызывает - это вводное слово. Однако ни в том, ни в другом случае, обособление не нужно, вводное слово стоит после союзов употребленных в присоединительном значении.

Comment: В таком случае (после присоединительных союзов), запятая ставится один раз - только после вводного слова.

Comment: Да, но не перед ним.

Comment: Серж,  сравните два высказывания. (Фраза 1) Подстановка, ВООБЩЕ ГОВОРЯ, не лучший способ для решения подобных задач (получается такое механическое решение). (Фраза 2) Подстановка всегда формальна, она меняет структуру предложения. И ВООБЩЕ это не лучший метод в любых случаях. А теперь сравните два рассуждения. В первом случае мы сразу используем обобщенную оценку, используя вводное слово, затем мысль можно развить дальше или закончить ее на той фразе..

Comment: Во втором случае мы сначала рассуждаем о чем-то, а с помощью наречия ВООБЩЕ подводим итог, делаем вывод (первый довод, второй довод, подведение итога).   В приведенном примере можно ориентироваться на союзы. Присоединительный союз  И - это, скорее, подведение итогов обсуждения (наречие). Присоединительный союз А - это открытие новой темы (вводное слово)

Comment: Вера, давайте исходить из значения наречия. Какое значение(если допустить, что это наречие), оно имеет?

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, в обоих случаях возможно обособление. Если можно добавить слово ***говоря***, то это всегда вводное слово и обособляется.